# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused for Laravel site

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, hosting

I get this error when i try to host my laravel project at [000webhost](https://000webhost.com/):

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `berita` where `id_berita` between 10046 and 10047)
```

This is my `.env`:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=id12858572_rpl_smkn2
DB_USERNAME=id12858572_rpl_smkn2
DB_PASSWORD=********
```

This is the first time i got this error, i have checked similar question, but it has not helped me. Any ideas what´s wrong?

[Picture for DB_NAME and DB_USERNAME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBWMX.png)

Comment: have you used php artisan config:cache?

Comment: this problem was solved, problem is on my `.htaccess` file

Comment: Add the answer so that in future will help to someone else :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to add this code in my .htaccess file

after this code :

```
# HTID:13056320: DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES BELOW
php_value display_errors 1
# DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THIS LINE AND THE LINES ABOVE HTID:13056320:
```

add this :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

i think it should be something in your `.env` file

1. is the database host reachable by port `3306`?
2. can you login using mysql cli to the database according to your credentials in `env` ?
3. what's the mysql service status ?

one more, maybe its your laravel cache so you might considering clear your cache

Comment: database is online, how to check that?
_Sorry but, i'm new in this_

Comment: 2. i can login to db with db_username and db_password from  `.env`  file

Comment: you can check using `'telnet yourdatabaseip/host 3306` and to login into your database if you're using like ubuntu, you can `mysql -h localhost -u id12858572_rpl_smkn2  -p`

Comment: 1. database is not reached by port 3306 or 33060, why?

Comment: have you checked mysql database service?

Comment: how to check it?

Comment: chek this https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/how-to-connect-to-database-using-php/42093?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=65b64195d330ba9b3b9b88e05f0c7531cee42033-1583812901-0-AZrifu9Qhdi9L4Clf0DXpReTrznoCKHEbn9mbGd1-GP4skBITAde4l0pWlb2EL_tDPaC-j1YMPEZorkKJq1s8wMBekMFb1Ne12DTIKZXKwv4cOWUf0oIfS8ejvEMfzkwzLR6TD_KLOXLqmRqeh2-SlcuuqVN0qH3ek7X4OYviVXqmraewfc1UJ9oT7qhxkOIKwpOdU8G2od_bIyrffQLBa0hSBSkFP_Tb75hYytJryxz-EnAWJl_Hd8bO-Br2f3-pWBGQm0BIwbYmuTX4Fgq-Ls_jMFxPS5KAnCO_qy1yzK1oNaR3_LKZOPhwT5pL-TQF7PgVm38TWvQF6XdmMEHkhs

Comment: sooo.. its a wrap?